# When will PHP 5.4 appear in default OS X installations?

Tags: software-update, php

I am wondering when PHP 5.4 will appear in default OS X installations, or as part of official Software Update.

Does anyone have historical information on how late after release of PHP 5.2 that PHP 5.2 was included in OS X, as an indication of how quick/conservative they are?

Comment: We do not work for Apple.Inc, and even if we did, we could not disclose that information.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, nobody here has a crystal ball connected to the open source adoption strategy team at Cupertino. If you want to do the historical research yourself, you can have a look at [Apple Open Source](http://opensource.apple.com) which includes all the open source packages in OS X since 10.0.